# data structure for finding the substring from large number of strings

Tags: algorithm

My problem statement is that I am given millions of strings, and I have to find one sub-string which can be present in any of those strings.
e.g. given is "xyzoverflowasxs, werstackweq" etc. and I have to find a given sub string named as "stack", which should return "werstackweq". What kind of data structure we can use for solving this problem ?

I think we can use suffix tree for this , but wanted some more suggestions for this problem.

Comment: Suffix trees and tries seem to be good enough for this problem, right?

Comment: tries can not be the solution for this problem.

Comment: I don't really understand the comments. The question says "I think we can use suffix tree.. but wanted some more suggestions", and the comments say that suffix trees are good for this.

Comment: @AmiTavory oops, I missed that last sentence. Removing my comment. However I don't understand why OP is reclutant to use suffix tree. This approach is optimal from algorithmic perspective.

Comment: @Aivean I don't really know, but there could be plausible reasons: 1. he wants to implement it using only the standard library of some language 2. he's looking for more memory-efficient solutions (runtime complexity is important, but not everything). 3. curiosity?

Comment: @AmiTavory valid point, but I'd rather have answer from the OP why suffix trees are not working for him. I mean we can hypothize about the reason, but it would be much simpler if we know the actual one so we can suggest most suitable solution.

Comment: Aivean , Ami : thanks for posting your views.There is no such reason for rejection of suffix tree. I was just curios to know is there any alternative of suffix tree for solving this kind of problem ? I am also wondering , if use of regular expression can be a better alternative to solve this problem(I am not sure how regular expression works on a given string ?, do they use some special data structure or they do some kind of brute force for finding all of the possible solutions ?).

Comment: @pjain, can you clarify, do you need to perform multiple queries against your "millions of strings" or search is performed only once? If later, you don't need suffix trees.

Comment: No, it is not once, it will be many a times(that's why I stated that suffix tree will work)

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to go is with a dictionary holding the actual words, and another data structure pointing to entries within this dictionary. One way to go would be with suffix trees and their variants, as mentioned in the question and the comments. I think the following is a far simpler (heuristic) alternative.

Say you choose some integer *k*. For each of your strings, finding the *k* [Rabin Fingerprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint) of length-*k* within each string should be efficient and easy (any language has an implementation).

So, for a given *k*, you could hold two data structures:

- A dictionary of the words, say a [hash table based on collision lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_list_head_cells)
- A dictionary mapping each fingerprint to an array of the linked-list node pointers in the first data structure.

Given a word of length *k* or greater, you would choose a *k* subword, calculate its Rabin fingerprint, find the words which contain this fingerprint, and check if they indeed contain this word.

---

The question is which *k* to use, and whether to use multiple such *k*. I would try this experimentally (starting with simultaneously a few small *k* values for, say, 1, 2, and 3, and also a couple of larger ones). The performance of this heuristic anyway depends on the distribution of your dictionary and queries.